# triple tensor product in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hpc

I am translating some code from C to numpy and this particular snippet is showing some significant slowdowns. It seems just replacing the inner loops with sums over numpy arrays is not enough. Does anyone have a suggestion to recover some of the original performance?

I would prefer to avoid using scipy.weave. I am wondering if I can somehow use the convolution functions, but the documentation is a bit thin on those and there seems to be several options (scipy.signal, ndimage, numpy.convolve, etc). Would it be possible to use the Einstein summation functions (`einsum`) or `tensordot`? For the `tensordot` I think I would need to do X,Y,Z separately?

I have set these values to random so it is possible to just cut and paste, but I should note there is some structure to MX,MY and MZ, `M(i,j)` is a function of `|i-j|` and `M(i,j)=M(j,i)`

In response to some suggested edit, in general `n[0] != n[1] != n[2]`

```
n = np.array((50,50,50))
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.random(n)
C = np.zeros_like(A)
MX = np.random.random((n[0],n[0]))
MY = np.random.random((n[1],n[1]))
MZ = np.random.random((n[2],n[2]))

for i in xrange(n[0]):
    for j in xrange(n[1]):
        for k in xrange(n[2]):
            C[i,j,k]=(MX[i,:]*A[:,j,k]).sum() + (MY[j,:]*A[i,:,k]).sum() +(MZ[k,:]*A[i,j,:]).sum()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use np.einsum:

```
D = (  np.einsum('il,ljk->ijk', MX, A)
     + np.einsum('jl,ilk->ijk', MY, A)
     + np.einsum('kl,ijl->ijk', MZ, A))
```

The result is the same:

```
In [14]: np.allclose(C, D)
Out[14]: True
```

Here is a benchmark showing it's about ~170x faster:

```
In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: for i in xrange(n[0]):
    for j in xrange(n[1]):
        for k in xrange(n[2]):
            C[i,j,k]=((MX[i,:]*A[:,j,k]).sum()
                      + (MY[j,:]*A[i,:,k]).sum()
                      + (MZ[k,:]*A[i,j,:]).sum())
1 loops, best of 3: 2.95 s per loop


In [21]: %timeit D = (np.einsum('il,ljk->ijk',MX,A) + np.einsum('jl,ilk->ijk',MY,A) + np.einsum('kl,ijl->ijk',MZ,A))
100 loops, best of 3: 17.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Dang it, I've been scooped! :) Note: I think that's ~170x faster.

Comment: @farenorth: Not bad -- maybe next I'll [find a new element](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hktk-xyCCyY) :) (thanks for the correction).

Comment: This solution is also almost twice as fast as a naive use of scipy.weave  Thanks!